# Prevent buttons from submitting forms

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in JavaScript and HTML. I am trying to prevent buttons from submitting forms. It is not working with my below code. It is working when I remove the `type:button` and `return false` in the code but if I remove it is always submitting the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction1();return false;" style="font-size:24px">Button <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction1(){

        }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your form?

Comment: Type="button" will work, but show the relevant HTML

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission

Comment: @IsaacAbramowitz I would recommend not using click event but submit event

Comment: Doesn't the question I posted refer to submit events?

Answer (score -1):

### JQUERY

You should be able to do:

`$('#formid').submit(false);`

or

`$('#formid').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`

> To use the jquery library visit the official website
>   http://jquery.com/download/

### PURE JS

```
document.getElementById('formid').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Neither the question text, nor the code the question asker provided includes jQuery. If you're hellbent on suggestion a jQuery solution, it might be good to at least caveat it with the instruction they will need to add jQuery to their project.

Answer (score -1):

here is your example

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script>
    function countRabbits() {
      for(var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        alert("Rabbit number " + i);
      }
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="countRabbits()" value="Count rabbits"/>
</body>
</html>
```

First of all, take care about closed pair tags. In your snippet you have unclosed *script* tag. Don't use *button* where it isn't necessary, but use the input type button instead.